# I have multiple files and file with different versions . I need how to pick the highest numbered version from every file

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, rhel

I have multiple files and file with different versions . I need how to pick the highest numbered version from every file .

ex:

```
ac-1
ac-2
bc-1
bc-2
```

Desired output.

```
 ac-2,bc-2
```

Comment: It's completely unclear what your pattern is. Edit your question to include more details and use the formatting options.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the filenames in reverse and then select the first occurrence of each filename:

```
$ cat input                                                                                            
ac-1
ac-2
bc-1
bc-2

$ cat input | sort -r | awk -F '-' '!seen[$1]++' 
bc-2
ac-2
```

The awk command takes '-' as delimiter and then prints each line where an element first column (ac,ac,bc,bc) appeared first. This is of course assuming that the version number always starts after the first '-'.

Answer (score 0):

Short bash script that uses [GNU `datamash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) to find the maximums:

```
#!/bin/bash
mapfile -t files < <(datamash -st'-' -g1 max 2 < "$1")
IFS=,
echo "${files[*]}"
```

Usage:

```
$ ./example.sh input.txt
ac-2,bc-2
```